# joins in YII framework

Tags: yii

how would i write below query in yii framework

```
function Get_Services($user_id, $isResultSet = true){
    $sql = $this->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                    ->from(array('p' => 'phone_service'))
                    ->join(array('u' => 'user_preferences'), 'u.phone_service_id = p.phone_service_id')
                    ->where('u.user_preferences_name = ?', 'is_user_package_active')
                    ->where('p.user_id = ?', $user_id);

    if($isResultSet){
        return $sql->query()->fetchAll();
    }else{
        return $sql;
    }
}
```

Comment: yii documentation explains the joins and there are plenty of tutorials on that site as well.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly:

```
$sql = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
   ->from('phone_service p')
   ->join('user_preferences u', 'u.phone_service_id = p.phone_service_id')
   ->where('u.user_preferences_name = :upn', array(':upn' => 'is_user_package_active'))
   ->where('p.user_id = :uid', array(':uid' => $user_id)
   ->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
function Get_Services($user_id, $isResultSet = true){
        $sql = $this->select()
                    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                        ->from(array('p' => 'phone_service'))
                        ->join(array('u' => 'user_preferences'), 'u.phone_service_id = p.phone_service_id')
                        ->where('u.user_preferences_name = ?', 'is_user_package_active')
                        ->where('p.user_id = ?', $user_id);

        if($isResultSet){
            return $sql->queryAll();
        }else{
            return $sql;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->from('phone_service p')
->join('user_preferences u', 'u.phone_service_id = p.phone_service_id')
->where('u.user_preferences_name=:preferences',array(':preferences'=>'is_user_package_active'))
->where('p.user_id = :uid', array(':uid' => $user_id)
->queryAll(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create models for this, dive into relations using `Yii` and make your joins using active record and `with()` calls.

It could be a simple call after like

```
$records = PhoneServices::model()->with(array('userPreferences' => 
 array('condition' => 'userPreferences.user_preferences_name = 
 "is_user_package_active" ')))->findAllByAttributes(array('user_id' => $user_id));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
$sql = $this->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                    ->from(array('p' => 'phone_service'))
                    ->join(array('u' => 'user_preferences'), 'u.phone_service_id = p.phone_service_id')
                    ->where('u.user_preferences_name = ?', 'is_user_package_active')
                    ->where('p.user_id = ?', $user_id);
$query= $model->findAll($sql);
```